# Why is `Promise.then` called twice in a React component but not the console.log?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm very confused about the output of the following component:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

function Test(): React.ReactElement {
    console.log('render')
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => console.log('then ' + Math.random()))
    return <></>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Test />
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

It produces the following output at least in Chrome and Firefox:

```
00:46:30.264 render
00:46:30.267 then 0.5430663800781927
00:46:30.267 then 0.9667426372511254
```

I would rather expect to see the same count of messages. What am I missing?

Repro: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-frost-dmcsl

EDIT: I know that strict mode leads to extra rendering, but as stated, I would then expect the same count of messages.

EDIT 2: Both answers below are great. I would like to cite comment of @user56reinstatemonica8 here:

> Relevant: [Community feedback on console silencing](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21783)

Comment: Please add ***all*** of the code to reproduce this issue, not just a link to the sandbox.  The `<StrictMode>` is actually key to your issue.

Comment: Yeah, but why `render` is printed only once?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In React [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) react may run render *multiple* times, which could partly explain what you see.

But you correctly wondered *if that was the case and render was called multiple times, why was `render` not printed twice too*?

React modifies the console methods like `console.log()` to silence the logs in some cases. Here is a quote:

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in
> certain cases where a workaround can be used.

Apparently, it doesn't do so when the `console.log` is called from Promise callback. But it does so when it is called from render. More details about this are in the answer by @trincot.

Comment: …and that's also why you shouldn't schedule asynchronous callbacks (or worse, start asynchronous work) from inside the render method, but only from effects - an effect would run only once.

Comment: @Bergi That's actually the reason why a random framework shouldn't touch system function (which are commonly used for debugging) to do unexpected things.

Answer (score 44):

There is a second run of your render function when strict mode is enabled (only in development mode), but as discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18547), React will monkey patch `console` methods (calling `disableLogs();`) for the duration of that second (synchronous) run, so that it does not output.

The [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18547/files/b7e2345755e07c1174b3a755a78f36a6df7fa827) shows this code was inserted in `packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberBeginWork.js` in order to temporarily suppress logs (insertions marked with comment):

```js
  if (__DEV__) {
    ReactCurrentOwner.current = workInProgress;
    setIsRendering(true);
    nextChildren = renderWithHooks(
      current,
      workInProgress,
      render,
      nextProps,
      ref,
      renderExpirationTime,
    );
    if (
      debugRenderPhaseSideEffectsForStrictMode &&
      workInProgress.mode & StrictMode
    ) {
      disableLogs();       // <--
      try {                // <--
        nextChildren = renderWithHooks(
          current,
          workInProgress,
          render,
          nextProps,
          ref,
          renderExpirationTime,
        );
      } finally {          // <--
        reenableLogs();    // <--
      }                    // <--
```

Here is a version of your code that demonstrates it really runs twice:

```
var i = 0;
var myconsolelog = console.log; // Work around React's monkeypatching 

function Test(): React.ReactElement {
    i++;
    myconsolelog(i + ". render"); // will output twice now!
    Promise.resolve(i)
        .then((i) => console.log(i + ". then " + Math.random()));
    return <></>;
}
```

In my opinion, this log-suppression is a really *bad* design choice.

Comment: so it monkey patches in synchronous passes? That explains the doubt in my answer.

Comment: Yes, see in this [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/18547/files/b7e2345755e07c1174b3a755a78f36a6df7fa827), and see the pair `disableLogs` and `reenableLogs` around the call of `renderWithHooks`. Info added to answer.

Comment: Yeah... no idea why they felt the need to monkeypatch console methods. I understand that this second render may be a surprise... but IMHO it would have been better to write a debug message saying "Starting second rendering of component X, see `https://blah` for why this happens in development mode", i.e. they should have **added** their explanation of why the logs repeated instead of silencing them... Given that there are any number of other ways in which the user can detect the double render it doesn't really make sense to hide it...

Comment: Yeah, or to reduce noise, at the start of the second render cycle, they could do something like `console.groupCollapsed('Starting dev-only second render, see [link] for info')`, run `console.groupEnd` at the end, and capture all second-render log messages in a collapsed accordion. Minimal noise, no hidden surprises, clear what's happening.

Comment: Relevant: [Community feedback on console silencing](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21783)

Comment: I agree, this monkeypatch is a bad choice. Maybe, their devs use `console.log` quite often? ;)

Answer (score 2):

In case it might help anyone, you can monkey-patch `Object.defineProperties` to ignore any changes made to the `console` object, effectively preventing ReactDOM from monkey-patching `console.log`.

```js
const defineProperties = Object.defineProperties;
Object.defineProperties = function (o, props) {
  return o === console ? o : defineProperties(o, props);
};
```

Make sure to put this in development mode only (e.g. in create-react-app when `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'`), so that it doesn't end up in the production build.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to freeze console instead of patching things further?

Comment: If you freeze `console`, then React's attempt to patch console will throw an error, effectively blowing up the whole app.

Comment: Is it confirmed that defineProperties is used by React to patch? From what I see, it's regular assignment, which won't cause an error for frozen properties.

Comment: Yes, `console` is patched with `Object.defineProperties`, as can be seen here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v17.0.2/packages/shared/ConsolePatchingDev.js#L46 (most recent version of React, as of Feb 2022). This results  in errors like "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: info" being thrown from react-dom internals, if the console has been frozen.