# Why does Axios loads twice outside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

When I make a request through axios outside useEffect, it triggers twice, even when there is no other rendering happening on the page?.

Note that only axios is triggered twice, not the regular console.log

The complete code is as follows:

```
import axios from "axios";

function App() {

  console.log('only once') // this is triggered only once

  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  })

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Testing Axios</h2>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The output is like this:

[image]

Please help me understand why this happens like this? And it works fine when placed in useEffect, why would that make a difference as we are not changing anything in DOM anyway?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably due to `React.StrictMode`, it causes renders twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is \`Promise.then\` called twice in a React component but not the console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291908/why-is-promise-then-called-twice-in-a-react-component-but-not-the-console-log)

Answer (score 3):

Because my crystal ball says your component is wrapped in `React.StrictMode` (likely in your `ReactDOM.render` call).

[Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) calls your component functions twice [on purpose](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects) so you would know if you had side effects in them (and React would know if state or render results changed based on those side effects or state outside of the component, and it would loudly complain).

Don't do side effects without `useEffect`.

Comment: but if i do a regular console.log, it triggers only once. only axios is run twice

Comment: Some browsers' developer consoles happily deduplicate console messages. Try `console.log(Math.random())`...

Comment: @NabeelKhan that's, again, related to [how `StrictMode` works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68291908/1218980).

Comment: @EmileBergeron Oh, huh, I didn't know React patches `console.log`. Ew... 

Comment: @AKX it came out only once, axios still twice

Comment: @EmileBergeron please elaborate more? why is it showing axios twice while the regular console.log once?

Comment: @NabeelKhan Please read the answers in the question Emile linked. It's answered there.

Comment: @NabeelKhan the React team decided at some point to hide additional console logs triggered by the double rendering. This created [some more confusion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/21783), like you're experiencing today, so other solutions were eventually considered.