# Why App or Quiz component rendered two times?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

[image]

when I log any string in `App` component or `Quiz` component it appears two times in console.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291908/why-is-promise-then-called-twice-in-a-react-component-but-not-the-console-log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using `StrictMode`, which will cause multiple renders. [This in intentionally](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/96#discussion-3562310) done to help encourage developers use side effects properly. The double render will only happen in development and not in production.

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/15351640) for more information.

Strict mode is on because you have your components wrapped with `<React.StrictMode>`:

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
        ...
        ...
</React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted, but it _might_ be because of the _question_ not necessarily your _answer_. It's usually discouraged to answer questions that should be closed—in this case, either because the question is low quality (e.g., due to embedding code as an image), or because it's a duplicate. As far as I recall, part of that is because closed questions without any positive-scored answers will be automatically deleted after some time as part of clean-up processes, so downvoting further helps ensure that occurs.

Comment: Good to know, thank you Jeremy

Comment: Might be because this is a duplicate question and this answer effectively links to another answer.

Comment: Is linking to other answers frowned upon? I'm still a bit new here sorry

Comment: Not generally. If a question isn't a duplicate and a linked answer is only explaining a portion of the issue/solution (*i.e. clarifies so you don't duplicate effort*) and your answer adds helpful and relevant information, I don't think anyone would consider that unwelcome. `React.StrictMode` just happens to be one of those things that gets asked about a lot. Same with the "React state isn't updating immediately. Why?" sort of questions.

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom: It's totally fine to link to another answer for additional information or e.g. alternate approaches. If a question can be solved by an existing answer on another question, however, it's better to flag the question as a duplicate. Further, if you _do_ post an answer, it should still be self-contained and customized to the specifics of the question, instead of relying _primarily_ on the link, or just reiterating what's already stated in the linked answer.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!